# Android webview post not working with extraheader

Tags: java, android, post, webview, oauth-2.0

I am developing and android application for a client, I have a webview that load external links, some page have a form with post action, I use loadUrl (with override) to add extraHeaders (device type and access token), but with submit header is lost and I got 401 error.
Note : I can't make a big modification to the client site, I have to find a solution from android app side.

```
@SuppressLint("JavascriptInterface")
public void registerWebView() {
    Log.i("ACC TOKEN", DataSave.getAccessToken());
    mWebView = (AdvancedWebView) findViewById(R.id.mbrowser);
    mWebView.addHttpHeader(Utils.HEADER_AUTHORIZATION_NAME, "Bearer " + DataSave.getAccessToken());
    mWebView.addHttpHeader(Utils.HEADER_DEVICE_NAME, Utils.HEADER_DEVICE_VALUE);
    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
    }

    Log.i("WV FILE", AdvancedWebView.isFileUploadAvailable() + "");

    final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(mContext, new GestureListener());
    mWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            hideShareMenu();
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

    });



    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
            Log.i("WebView", "Got error !! " + errorCode);
        }

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String urlT) {
            Log.i("WebView", "Loading " + urlT);
            if (urlT.contains(Utils.URL_ROOT)) {
                view.stopLoading();
                view.loadUrl(urlT, getExtraHeaders());
                return true;
            }else{
                view.stopLoading();
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlT));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            handleNavigationUI(url);
        }

    });



    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);

    mPublicationIcon = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.publication);

    mSearchActionBar = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_find);
    mSearchActionBarHeight = Utils.dpToPx(mContext, 40);
    mSearchInput = (cEditText)findViewById(R.id.search_input);

    mPublicationIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mWebView.loadUrl(Utils.URL_ROOT + Utils.URL_PUBLICATION);
            toggleSearchbar(false, "");
            togglePublicationIcon(false);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: You need to add in some code and contexts for others to be able to help you out.

Comment: I added my registerWebView code, i make the url load from the menu class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem, it is very easy, just simple javascript code injection onPageFinished function.